# Gcloud app deploy gets stuck - How to troubleshooot

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, gcloud

I am trying to publish a simple .net core web application to GCloud. Created a docker file and deployed using the simple command

> gcloud app deploy app.yml

Nothing fancy really. The deployment gets stuck at the "Updating service" stage. Is there a way I can find out what's going on behind the scenes for me to progress it further?

[image]

Comment: The first deployment can take significantly longer than usual. Did the spinner stop spinning i.e. how did you infer that the deployment was stuck?

Comment: it just kept spinning. I did a subsequent deployment which went on for a while but did complete. My question was if there is a way to see more details of what actually is going on...

Comment: Please don't post text as images...

Comment: @DanCornilescu oK. will keep it in mind in future